# Select a text after alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm testing a syntax for an email input. And it is alerting some message on the web browser if the email syntax is wrong. After the user clicks ok on that messsage I want the browser to select the text.

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
document.body.appendChild(input);
input.onblur = function(){
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
    if(reg.test(this.value) == false){
        alert('Wrong syntax on e-mail');
        $(this).select();//This doesn't work!
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `this.focus();`?

Comment: doesn't work either. At least not in Chrome/Mac. I think the alert stops the browser from focusing and selecting.

Comment: Top level domains aren't limited to 2-4 characters. It is quite common to have `+` characters in the user part of the address. In short, your regex is horribly broken and will produce lots of false failures.

Comment: Can you come up with a solution? `/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z])+$/ ?`I'm pretty bad with regex

Comment: Can I add an event handler to the ok button?

Comment: [regular expression for email addresses according to the RFC](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting issue, it looks like a security-feature. Keep in mind that your script blocks the UI as long as you didn't type a accepted email-adress.

This works for me:

```
input.onblur = function(){
    var _this=this;
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
    if(reg.test(this.value) == false){
        alert('Wrong syntax on e-mail');
        setTimeout(function(){_this.select();},1)
    }
}
```

As you see it uses a timeout, but I don't think that the delayed call is the key, the important thing is the different scope where the function will be  executed now(scope is now window instead of the input).

Comment: I think the `onblur` event happens split of a second **before** the actual blur, thus focusing/selecting the textbox has no visible effect. Used the timeout trick too in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
document.body.appendChild(input);
input.onblur = function(){
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
    if(reg.test(this.value) == false){
        alert('Wrong syntax on e-mail');
        SelectText(this);
    }
} 

function SelectText(text) {

    if ($.browser.msie) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.opera) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    } else if ($.browser.safari) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.setBaseAndExtent(text, 0, text, 1);
    }
}
```